# What would happen to a diamond in the presence of oxygen and elevated temperature and how fast?

Tags: thermodynamics, carbon-allotropes

Let's say I have a $\pu{1cm^3}$  diamond and I put it into an oven where the temperature is about $\pu{ 400°C}$. We all know that diamond oxidizes. Would it evaporate or turn into graphite? If so, what would be the rate of reaction? Is there some way to calculate it?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond):

> Above $\pu{1700^\circ C}$ ($\pu{1973 K}$/$\pu{3583^\circ F}$) in vacuum or oxygen-free atmosphere, diamond converts into graphite; in air, transformation starts at $\pu{\approx 700^\circ C}$. Diamond's ignition point is $\pu{720–800^\circ C}$ in oxygen and $\pu{850–1000 ^\circ C}$ in air.
> [....]
>
> But diamonds (sp<sup>3</sup> carbon) are unstable against high temperature (above about $\pu{400 ^\circ C}$ ($\pu{752 ^\circ F}$)) under atmospheric pressure. The structure gradually changes into sp<sup>2</sup> carbon above this temperature. Thus, diamonds should be reduced under this temperature.

So even if the diamond doesn't reach the temperature of $\pu{700^\circ C}$  it still oxidizes. That's why I'm asking.